# Java Netty Websocket Client with multiframe support

Tags: java, websocket, netty, java-websocket

I'm straggling with a netty Websocket client. The client successfully receives single frame payload. When the payload is too large for a single frame, the client receives only the first frame. Obviously I committed some mistake, but I cannot find any proper documentation related to this topic.
Here is my pipeline:

```
        group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        final HubWebSocketClientHandler handler =
                new HubWebSocketClientHandler(
                        WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory.newHandshaker(
                                uri,
                                WebSocketVersion.V13,
                                null,
                                true,
                                new DefaultHttpHeaders()
                        ),
                        this,
                        hubEndpoint,
                        topicId,
                        endpoint
                );

        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group)
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
                        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                        if (sslCtx != null) {
                            p.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc(), host, port));
                        }
                        p.addLast(
                                new HttpClientCodec(),
                                new HttpObjectAggregator(65536),
                                WebSocketClientCompressionHandler.INSTANCE,
                                handler);
                    }
                });

        channel = b.connect(uri.getHost(), port).sync().channel();
        handler.handshakeFuture().sync();
```

And here is how I process the frames:

```
    WebSocketFrame frame = (WebSocketFrame) msg;
    if (frame instanceof TextWebSocketFrame) {
        TextWebSocketFrame textFrame = (TextWebSocketFrame) frame;
        textBuffer += textFrame.text();
        if (frame.isFinalFragment()) {
            service.onTextMessage(textBuffer);
            textBuffer = "";
        }
    } else if (frame instanceof PongWebSocketFrame) {
```

...
I receive the first frame that is marked as "Not final". I was expecting to receive another frame with the rest of the message, but it never comes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake. The next frame object is an instance of a class ContinuationWebSocketFrame. Here is a working code snippet:

```
     WebSocketFrame frame = (WebSocketFrame) msg;
    if (frame instanceof TextWebSocketFrame) {
        TextWebSocketFrame textFrame = (TextWebSocketFrame) frame;
        textBuffer += textFrame.text();
        if (frame.isFinalFragment()) {
            service.onTextMessage(textBuffer);
            textBuffer = "";
        }
    } else if (frame instanceof ContinuationWebSocketFrame) {
       textBuffer += ((ContinuationWebSocketFrame) frame).text();
        if (frame.isFinalFragment()) {
            service.onTextMessage(textBuffer);
            textBuffer = "";
        }
    }
```

...